# Get tagless elements in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Given the following `html` snippet:

```
<div class="mapCopy">
    <b>
        <a href="someurl.com">
          URL Text
        </a>
    </b>
    <br/>
       Address Line 1
    <br/>
       Address Line 2
    <br/>
       City, State, Zip
    <p>
        Phone: (123) 456-7890
    <br/>
        Fax: (123) 456-7890
    </p>
</div>
```

How might I extract only the Address Line 1, Address Line 2, City, State, and Zip?  I believe I should be able to iterate on the `div` and exclude any elements that have a `<b>` tag, but I'm unsure of the necessary syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract all children of the `<div>` that don't contain tags:

```
>>> S = BeautifulSoup("<div...")
>>> [child.strip() for child in S.find('div').children
...      if "<" not in str(child)
...      and len(child) > 1
... ]
['Address Line 1', 'Address Line 2', 'City, State, Zip']
```